# ios development : uilabel changes when button is clicked.

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am working on project ,, where i got struck ed, I have one button and two images for it ![enter image description here][1]
when i pressed button the label should changed to +1 for present image is selected as p image.
 and for absent the label text should changed to -1 and goes on 
help me any one for this .

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear.

Comment: I am having UIButton. and when the view appears it shows the background image as absent.png. and when i click on same button the image which i get is present.png which is selected is YES. and at the same time the absent label should decrease when i press button and should increase the present label value as one. like wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Boolean

```
bool isPresent;
int presentCount = 0;
int absentCount = 0;
```

In `viewDidLoad` set it as false

Now in button clicked method

```
- (IBAction)button_pressed:(id)sender {

if(isPresent == true){
 // change your button image
 present count --;
 absentCount ++;
// set this count on your label text
}
else{

present count ++;
 absentCount --;
}
}
```

I hope i understood your problem and this is the the solution you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am new to ios so , i don't know how to question . anyways thanks once again

Comment: @SantoshSugur . Its ok. No problem. Hope you got some help from my naswer